# Simultaneous result from single parameter SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following t-sql:

```
declare @startdate datetime, @finishdate datetime;
declare @declinerate float, @setpoint float;
declare @recoveredmw;

set @startdate = '2016-01-01';
set @finishdate = '2016-12-31'
set @declinerate = 0.0972 / 100;
set @setpoint = 98;
set @recoveredmw = @setpoint - 1;

;WITH ctetest AS 
(
    SELECT      
        @StartDate AS CDate, 
        @setpoint as Case2, 
        0 as OLNo

    UNION ALL

    SELECT      
        dateadd(day,1,CDate),
        CASE 
           WHEN Case2 < @recoveredMW THEN @setpoint 
                                     ELSE (1 - @declinerate1) * Case2 
        END,
        OLNo + (CASE WHEN Case2 < @recoveredMW THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    FROM        
        ctetest 
    WHERE       
        dateadd(day, 1, CDate) <= @finishdate
)
SELECT * 
FROM ctetest OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Then the result should be:

```
---------------------------------
CDate          Case2       OLNo
---------------------------------
2016-01-01     98          0
2016-01-02     97.9        0
2016-01-03     97.81       0
ff.
2016-12-30     97.62       30
2016-12-31     97.52       30
```

It creates a data from 1st of January until the end of december base on `@startdate` and `@finishdate` parameter.

What I want is create a simultaneous `@recoveredMW`. Let say the `@setpoint` is 98 then it will create the result above which is `@recoveredMW` is minus 1 from the `@setpoint`. After `2016-12-31`, it will create another raw data start from the beginning but the `@recoveredMW` is minus 2 and so on.

Result sample:

```
---------------------------------
CDate          Case2       OLNo
---------------------------------
2016-01-01     98          0
2016-01-02     97.9        0
2016-01-03     97.81       0
ff.
2016-12-30     97.62       30
2016-12-31     97.52       30
2016-01-01     97          0        <-- New RawData after 2016-12-31, @recoveredMW-2
2016-01-02     96.91       0
2016-01-03     96.81       0
ff.
2016-12-31     96.53       30
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add another anchor member to your ctetest after the first anchor member

```
        SELECT      @startdate AS CDate, 
                    @setpoint - 1 as Case2, 
                    0 as OLNo
```

if you want the result to order separately, add another column to differentiate the original run with `@setpoint` from `@setpoint - 1`

here is the modified query

```
;WITH ctetest AS 
        (
            SELECT      1 AS Data,   -- Added
            @startdate AS CDate, 
                        @setpoint as Case2, 
                        0 as OLNo

            UNION ALL

            SELECT      2 as Data,
            @startdate AS CDate, 
                        @setpoint - 1 as Case2, 
                        0 as OLNo

            UNION ALL

            SELECT      Data,
            dateadd(day,1,CDate),
                        CASE WHEN Case2 < @recoveredmw THEN @setpoint ELSE (1 - @declinerate) * Case2 END,
                        OLNo + (CASE WHEN Case2 < @recoveredmw THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            FROM        ctetest 
            WHERE       dateadd(day, 1, CDate) <= @finishdate
        )
        SELECT      * 
        FROM        ctetest 
    order by    Data, CDate
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

EDIT 1 :

```
;WITH 
numbers AS          -- added
(
    SELECT  n = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  n = n + 1
    FROM    numbers
    WHERE   n < 999
),
ctetest AS 
        (
            SELECT      n AS Data,                   -- change
            @startdate AS CDate, 
                        CAST (n as FLOAT) as Case2,   -- change
                        0 as OLNo
        FROM        numbers                           -- change
        WHERE   n   <= @setpoint                 -- change

            UNION ALL

            SELECT      Data,
            dateadd(day,1,CDate),
                        CASE WHEN Case2 < @recoveredmw THEN @setpoint ELSE (1 - @declinerate) * Case2 END,
                        OLNo + (CASE WHEN Case2 < @recoveredmw THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            FROM        ctetest 
            WHERE       dateadd(day, 1, CDate) <= @finishdate
        )
        SELECT      * 
        FROM        ctetest 
    order by    Data DESC, CDate     -- change
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: That is good, but I want the simultaneous recoveredmw until 1. The answer is until 96 only.

Comment: mate... That is awesome. Cheers, :)

Comment: i am using a recursive cte for the number table. For better performance, build it as a permemant table. Search for Tally /  Number table and there are lots of reference on that